# Paramiko SFTPClient.get fails with "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" when using S3 path

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paramiko

Trying to download a file from SFTP path to S3 bucket using Paramiko module in python

```
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log")

# Open a transport
host, port = RECV_IP_ADDRESS, 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

# Auth
username, password = "pi", "raspberry"
transport.connect(None, username, password)
# Go!
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
# Download
1. sftp.get(remote_path, "/home/dir/pp/"+file_name)
2. sftp.get(remote_path, str("s3://bucket/pp/sftp_testing/"+file_name))

# Close
if sftp: sftp.close()
if transport: transport.close()
```

while using the same code with the local path(line 1), the code is working fine. But when the S3 path(line 2) is used it is getting failed.

Error:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://bucket/pp/sftp_testing/test.csv'

Comment: Why are you using an SFTP protocol to retrieve content from Amazon S3? Can you point us to any documentation that says this should work?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein- This script is retrieving files from SFTP and not from AWS S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boto3 library is for interacting with Amazon S3 in Python .

```
import paramiko
import boto3

paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log")


host, port = RECV_IP_ADDRESS, 22
username, password = "pi", "raspberry"


s3_bucket_name = "bucket"
s3_folder_path = "pp/sftp_testing/"


remote_path = "/path/to/file.csv"
file_name = "test.csv"


transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(None, username, password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)


local_path = "/home/dir/pp/" + file_name
sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)


s3 = boto3.client("s3")
s3_key = s3_folder_path + file_name
s3.upload_file(local_path, s3_bucket_name, s3_key)


sftp.close()
transport.close()
```